# powershell compare properties of two network adapters side-by-side

Tags: powershell, object, properties

I'm just beginning Powershell, and I want to look at all the properties of two network adapters side-by-side in order to easily see differences.

I've used:

Get-NetAdapter -name "(adapter's name)" | Format-List -Property "*"

multiple times to display all the properties of each adapter one after the other, but it's hard to compare this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perhaps easiest way of doing this is to DIY create a csv file.

I think this will work:

```
# get the info for the two adapters
$info = Get-NetAdapter -Name 'LAN-connection 1', 'LAN-connection 2'

# create a template string to output csv rows.
# use the systems ListSeparator character so you can double click to open in Excel
$csvline = '"{0}","{1}","{2}"' -replace ',', (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ListSeparator

# create a List object to store the content in
$csvOut = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

# add a headers line
[void]$csvOut.Add(($csvline -f 'Property', $info[0].Name, $info[1].Name))

$info[0].PsObject.Properties | Select-Object * | ForEach-Object {
    # get the matching property fro the second adapter
    $prop2 = $info[1].PsObject.Properties[$_.Name]
    # add the data row
    [void]$csvOut.Add(($csvline -f $_.Name, $_.Value, $prop2.Value))
} 

# show on screen (although it will probably not fit..)
$csvOut | ConvertFrom-Csv -UseCulture

# write to CSV file to open in Excel
$csvOut | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\AdapterInfo.csv'
```